# getData bringing the parent node element instead of the child node element [Angular Typescript]

Tags: angular, typescript, oop

I am trying to create a dynamic data dropdown menu with Google Material.

[This is the repository I gathered the code:](https://github.com/shhdharmen/mat-menu-dynamic-data)

I only changed the context of the fruits to the my actual context, and it still not bringing any data. **It was supposed to be and dropdown menu of semesters, which when the users click on the button, it displays the years and its semesters (It can be only 1° and 2°).**

Mind you, that I also changed the context of the original code to the same as mine, and it worked. I also didn't understand why the dropdown menu is bringing the parent node, which is the year, instead of bringing the child node, which is 1 or 2, referring to the semester.

**this is my semester.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { delay, of } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PeriodoService {

  dataMap = new Map<string, string[]> ([

    ['2024', ['1','2']],
    ['2023', ['1','2']],
    ['2022', ['1','2']],
    ['2021', ['1','2']],
    ['2020', ['1','2']]

  ]);

  rootLevelNodes: string[] = ['2024', '2023', '2022', '2021'];


  getChildren(node: string) {
    // adding delay to mock a REST API call

    return of(this.dataMap.get(node)).pipe(delay(1000));

  }

  isExpandable(node: string): boolean {

    return this.dataMap.has(node);

  }
}
```

**This is my semester.ts:**

```
export interface Periodo {
  ano: number;
  periodos: Array<PeriodoItem>;
}

export interface PeriodoItem {
  id: string;
  periodo: number;
}
```

**This is my dynamic-mat-menu.html:**

```
<button *ngIf="isRootNode" mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
  {{ trigger }}
</button>
<button *ngIf="!isRootNode" mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
  {{ trigger }}
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">

  <ng-container *ngFor="let node of data; let i = index">

    <button mat-menu-item>

      <app-dynamic-mat-menu [trigger]="node" *ngIf="isExpandable(node); else menuItem">
      </app-dynamic-mat-menu>

    </button>

    <ng-template #menuItem>

      <button mat-menu-item>{{ node }}</button>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>


  <button *ngIf="isRootNode" mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
    {{ trigger }}   
  </button>

  <button *ngIf="!isRootNode" mat-menu-item ="menu" (menuOpened)="getData(trigger)">
    {{ trigger }}
  </button>

</mat-menu>
```

**This is my dynamic-mat-menu.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { PeriodoService } from '../../../shared/services/periodo.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-mat-menu',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-mat-menu.component.html',
  styleUrl: './dynamic-mat-menu.component.scss',
})
export class DynamicMatMenuComponent {
  @Input() data: string[] = [];
  @Input() trigger = "Períodos";
  @Input() isRootNode = false;

  isLoading = false;
  dataLoaded = false;


  constructor(private periodoService: PeriodoService) {}

  getData(node: string) {
    console.log(`Node: ${node}`);
    if (this.dataLoaded) {
      console.log(`entrou aqui: ${this.dataLoaded}`);
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.periodoService.getChildren(node).subscribe((d) => {
        this.data = d?.slice() || [];
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.dataLoaded = true;
      });
    }
  }

  isExpandable(node: string) {
    return this.periodoService.isExpandable(node);
  }
}
```

I Already tried using console.log on the dynamic-mat-menu.ts. It doesn't show any error on the console in element inspection, but when I do the same thing with the original code of this person, it works just as fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAluM.jpg)